# write a query in h2 database to convert date format

Tags: java, sql, oracle, junit, h2

I am writing junit tests that uses h2 . Oracle uses a different format ('03-february-20'). H2 database throws error for that format ('2020-02-03').

I need to convert a string `03-february-20` into date `2020-02-03` in a query in h2 database. Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PARSEDATETIME](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#parsedatetime) for example:

```sql
create table DATE_EXAMPLE (
    EXAMPLE DATE
);
insert into DATE_EXAMPLE values ('2020-02-03');
select * from DATE_EXAMPLE where EXAMPLE = PARSEDATETIME('03-february-20','dd-MMMM-yy');
```

Comment: Thanks so much Oleg. I will try this today

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear exactly what you are doing.  Oracle's DATE data type has no "format".  Or rather, it is an internal, binary format.  If you want to select a column of DATE datatype, and convert that to a string representation (for consumption by humans or some other process that expects a string representation of a date, then you would use the to_char function:

```
select to_char(my_date,'dd-Mon-yyyy') from mytable;
```

and use any format mask you need to produce the results you want.  The format mask I used was the 'dd-Mon-yyyy', which would present today's date as 27-Feb-2020.

Comment: Hi, I need to convert from a string to date in H2 database. I need to write a select query that would convert a string of the type '03-february-20' to date of type '2020-02-03' and filter records where val_date column =  '2020-02-03'

Comment: Where does the string come from?  You tagged your question as 'oracle' and mentioned oracle in your initial post, so I assumed you were pulling it from an oracle database.  So what is the _oracle_ question here?