# DATE_FORMAT function compatibility issue in JPA test

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, h2, jpql

Our project uses MySQL in development & production environment and uses H2 Database in test environment.

I have JPA method using JPQL like:

```
@Query(value = 
"SELECT new some.package.SomeDTO(DATE_FORMAT(t.createdAt, '%Y%m%d'), t.id) from Table T")
```

As you can see, Our legacy code use DATE_FORMAT function in order to make LocalDateTime field to String like 'yyyyMMdd'.

It dosen't cause any problem when we use MySQL, but in tests(using H2 Database), it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract ... at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery`  .

I know that since H2 doesn't have DATE_FORMAT function, it is obvious to failed at valiating the jpql query.

We didn't recognize the problem before because our project didn't have any DataJpaTest or SpringBootTest... But I want to add those tests, so recently I met the problem even though the project has been a few years.

I used `MODE=MySQL` to make the function compatible, but it doesn't work.

I tried to make the query to be native, but I need to get DTOs as result from the query. So in order to make the query native, I must use Projection (making the DTO to be an interface) or use @SqlResultSetMapping.

But... Our project is a huge legacy, so I'm afraid to make such changes like changing my DTO class to be an interface.

I wanted to get some help about what I should do.
I may use @SqlResultSetMapping so that I could make only little changes, but I'm not sure it's a best solution.
Maybe I should change the String(yyyyMMdd) field in the DTO to be a LocalDate field, and also change all the service codes using the DTOs? It will cause big change, but should I?

I will be appriciated if you suggest any idea.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the most obvious solution is to use the same database across all environments. Using a different database product for testing is simply asking for trouble!

Comment: h2 has another function https://stackoverflow.com/a/60443680/5193536  you should use a wrapper for multiple databases

Comment: Many options. One I suggest for DB specific problems is to use named queries in the entities (or in an orm.xml file). You can then override the named queries with ones specific to the test DB through configuration, so it uses something similar enough like PARSEDATETIME. Alternatively, you can write your own H2 platform classes to implement DATE_FORMAT so it will be accepted, and possibly converted to PARSEDATETIME (or your own database function) in the generated SQL. How to write something like that depends on your JPA provider